# What does "12MP + 12MP Camera" mean in the specs of a mobile phone?

Tags: resolution, camera-basics, megapixels, mobile

I have seen some mobile phone specifications that mention "12MP + 12MP Camera", such as these [specs for a Samsung Note 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I518v.jpg):

```
12MP + 12MP Camera
8MP Front Camera
6.3" Display
64 GB Memory
6 GB Ram
2.3 + 1.7 GHz Octa Core
```

Does "12MP + 12MP" mean that the camera has 24 megapixels in the camera, or just 12 megapixels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search indicates that that "12MP + 12MP" means exactly that: *two* 12MP cameras. One is a "standard" camera, for the other several possibilities exist (depending on maker): monochrome, wide angle, or tele lens. The 8MP is a 3rd camera facing the other way (for "selfies" while watching the screen).

I would expect the phone info tells you what that particular phone has

Comment: its Samsung Note 8

Comment: [here](http://www.samsung.com/uk/smartphones/galaxy-note8/spec-plus/) and [here](http://www.samsung.com/uk/smartphones/galaxy-note8/camera/) ...

Comment: is that meens both camera together we can take 24MP pictures?

Comment: @RANSARA009 no, You can take 2x 12MP photos. There is no indication whether both cameras have the same focal length or colors - and they certainly don't have the same position.

Comment: According to [Galaxy Note 8 specs at DPReview](https://www.dpreview.com/news/5028949765/samsung-galaxy-note-8-comes-with-12mp-stabilized-dual-camera-and-6-3-display), one rear camera is **26mm Wide angle with 12MP 1/2.55" sensor (1.4 µm pixel size), F1.7 and OIS**. The other is **2x Tele with 12MP 1/3.6" sensor (1.0 µm pixel size), F2.4 and OIS**. The front camera is **8 MP / F1.7 front camera, 1/3.6" sensor**.